# Adding Custom class in TableViewController in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've been trying to add a custom class named ThirdViewController to My TableView controller which is a third tab of my Tab Bar Controller. When i try to use a View Coontroller it displays but for table View controller which is required, it doesnt show any suggestion in my custom class.PFB the image for the same. [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AV4QH.jpg)

Comment: whats the parent class of `ThirdViewController `?

Comment: @LalKrishna  class ThirdViewController: UITableViewController {} now i have used UITableViewController and its showing in my storyboard. thanks for that. but can i inherit multiple things like UITableViewCOntroller and UIViewController?

Comment: UITableViewController itself is derived from UIViewController. @Gaurav

Comment: thanks rahul. pretty messed with ios. definitely need to enroll to a ios course.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply try creating UIViewController class and then use UITableView in that view controller